# Is it strange to put “calm“ and “clamorous“ in a sentence?

Tags: quotes, confusables

Calm and clamorous are opposite in meaning, but their pronunciation and spelling are a little similar.

If I wrote a sentence of:

> “Always keep calm in clamorous world.“

Would people know what I mean?

Is it an amusing quote?

Comment: Yes, your readers are smart, even in **a** clamorous world.

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter that they have opposite meanings, when they describe different things!

Comment: It is actually quite a good sentence. It uses alliteration (**c**alm and **c**lamorous) and apposition (or opposition, or irony if you prefer) with the two opposite terms. As such, it is quite memorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree it is an interesting idea to use the two words in one sentence.  As Yosef Baskin subtly indicates, though, your sentence needs an article before *clamorous world* because *world* is technically what is called a common noun.

From the *Chicago Manual of Style*, 2017, section 5.5:

> A common noun is the generic name of one item in a class or group
> {a chemical}{a river} {a pineapple} .... A common noun is usually
> used with a determiner—that is, an article or other word (e.g.,
> *some, few*) that indicates the number and definiteness of the
> noun element {a loaf} {the day} {some person}.

This is true even though you have characterized your world as clamorous. Depending on what you want to say, insert *a* if you mean to refer to one of many possible worlds, or *the*, if you mean to say our known world is ever and only clamorous.